# How to fix invisible desktop icon text with DreamScene

Tags: windows-7, icons, colors

I have a problem using [DreamScene](http://www.dreamscene.org/), that software is used to make video files into desktop background (like animated wallpaper).

The problem is when I activate DreamScene, the video file become my desktop background but all the fonts of the icon becomes transparent just like in the picture.

I tried to change the color in window color appearance but the color button is disabled.

[image: Transparent font color of the icon]

Comment: Even if you could change the icon color, wouldn’t it just become unreadable again when you use a different video, or are you going to change the color every time you change the video?

Comment: So do this mean that there is no solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, there is, see my new answer I posted. It works fine even after reboot. (I used it for a year now and it works perfectly.) You can accept the answer after 7 years LOL

Answer (score 1):

To solve problems with invisible Icon texts, you can follow this procedure:

- First, do all the 10 or so steps that they recommend involving the read only image files
- Then right click `My Computer`, then select `Properties`, `Advanced System Settings`, choose the `Advanced Tab`, then `Performance Settings`, and **uncheck** the option `Use Drop Shadows for Desktop Icons`

Removing the Icon shadow will allow your texts to be visible while dreamscene is running. If you've unchecked the option and your font is still transparent, make sure you find the video you want to use and set it to desktop again.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no built-in](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-you-change-icon-text-color-in-windows-7/b913c2c8-133c-4308-9987-47e6759f5c20) way to change the color of icon labels, but I have seen [third-party programs](https://www.google.com/search?q=icon+text+color&safe=off) in the past that could set the icon color; most notably [Iconoid](http://www.sillysot.com/).

Comment: I have tried Iconoid but it doesn't do anything. I tried to change font color of the icon, but the color doesn't change.

Comment: [Turn off the icon drop-shadow.](http://marksxp.mvps.org/WindowsXP/boarders.php)

Comment: Then the font color is completely gone. I have disabled icon drop shadow and used iconoid to change font color but nothing happened.

Comment: What do you mean by “nothing happened”? You just said the color is gone (which is what your screenshot looks like as well).

Comment: I mean it is unreadable if i disable icon drop shadow. The font color remained transparent.

Comment: Yes, that’s how it looks in your screenshot, *with* the drop-shadow too. I’m trying to find a way to [enable the colored background](https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+windows+desktop+icon+background+color) of desktop icon text, but it looks like Windows 7 just doesn’t have it anymore.

Comment: Please take a look at this [link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/fix-transparent-or-invisible-desktop-icon-text-after-installing-dreamscene-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Ah, well there you have it. It’s a bug caused by hacking DreamScene to install it on 7 where it is not meant to be. Did you try the hacks to work-around it? If so, did they work for you?

Comment: The hack doesn't work, i tried the picture position to fill and i redo the video to desktop background, but the font kept transparent. And there is no file to download on that link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to handle this problem of invisible icon text. [See this post.](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/25758-fix-icon-text-in-windows-7-for-dreamscene-patch/)

To quote the steps:

> 1. right click a video and set to desktop background
> 2. set folder options to show hidden files
> 3. go to --> C:\Users#username#\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows DreamScene
> 4. there should be 2 image files of the dreamscene running (1 hidden/greyed)
> 5. set both files to “read only” & uncheck “hidden”
> 6. right click desktop > personalise > desktop background
> 7. under windows dreamscene, you should see both image files
> 8. make sure both are checked by clicking check boxes next to them
> 9. set Picture position: Fill
> 10. save changes

This procedure was verified on Windows 7 Professional and I have been using it with no problems for a year.

Answer (score -1):

I found a complete solution to the problem (permament fix) here:

Just only install fixed activator and add .reg file to system registry

http://chomikuj.pl/ZebMCS/Windows+7+(123)/DreamScene/Windows7+(Icon+Fixed)+DreamScene+Activator,7242237894.rar(archive)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.